# Is this problem mistaken? $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-\sin a}{x-a}=\cos a$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Prove that
> $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-\sin a}{x-a}=\cos a$$

I found a counter argument that when $a\neq 0$ and $0< a < \frac{1}{4\pi}$, the limit is equal to $\frac{\sin(a)}{a}$,which is greater than $\cos a$, based on the fundamental properties of sine and cosine. And I've also verified the equation is true if we turn $x\to0$ into $x\to a$. But in my solution manual, people just proved this by $x\to0$ naturally.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You're right, it's probably a typo in the question. It should probably be $x\to a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, the limit as written is not true for most values of $a$. This does appear to be a typo for $\lim_{x \to a}$, possibly in both the question and the solution section.